# python datetime to float with millisecond precision

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

What is a classy way to store date and time information in a float in python with millisecond precision?
Edit: I'm using python 2.7

I've hacked together the following:

```
DT = datetime.datetime(2016,01,30,15,16,19,234000) #trailing zeros are required
DN = (DT - datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)).total_seconds()
print repr(DN)
```

Output:

```
507482179.234
```

And then to revert back to datetime:

```
DT2 = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(0, DN)
print DT2
```

Output:

```
2016-01-30 15:16:19.234000
```

But I'm really looking for something a little more classy and robust.

In matlab I would use the `datenum` and `datetime` functions:

```
DN = datenum(datetime(2016,01,30,15,16,19.234))
```

And to revert back:

```
DT = datetime(DN,'ConvertFrom','datenum')
```

Comment: Thanks J.F. Sebastian, you're right, I missed that question as I wasn't aware it was called a timestamp. I'll look into the other question and answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Python 2:

```
def datetime_to_float(d):
    epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    total_seconds =  (d - epoch).total_seconds()
    # total_seconds will be in decimals (millisecond precision)
    return total_seconds

def float_to_datetime(fl):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(fl)
```

---

Python 3:

```
def datetime_to_float(d):
    return d.timestamp()
```

The python 3 version of `float_to_datetime` will be no different from the python 2 version above.

Comment: your Python 2/3 `datetime_to_float()` versions are inconsistent unless your local timezone is UTC.

Comment: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp() can also be used to avoid timezone conflict

Answer (score 15):

In Python 3 you can use: [`timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) (and [`fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) for the inverse).

Example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now.timestamp()
1455188621.063099
>>> ts = now.timestamp()
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 11, 11, 3, 41, 63098)
```

Comment: ``datetime.datetime`` seems to have no ``timestamp`` attribute, is this for python 3? I'm using 2.7 (and forgot to mention, sorry) Edit: from jatinderjit's answer it seems .timestamp is indeed python 3 only