# How to convert datetime object to float? AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'datetime_to_float'

Tags: python, datetime, error-handling

I have datetime data which is of the following shape:

***yyyy-mm-dd hh:minmin:secsec + hh:minmin***

For example this one: *2020-02-01 01:00:00+01:00*

I now would like to convert it to float. I used the function I found the solution of this question: [python datetime to float with millisecond precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337299/python-datetime-to-float-with-millisecond-precision)

```
def datetime_to_float(d):
    return d.timestamp()
```

I applied this function to my datetime-object with this code:

```
time_in_float = []

for i in time:
    time_in_float.append(i.datetime_to_float())
```

And got this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f6272033e480> in <module>()
      2 
      3 for i in time:
----> 4     time_in_float.append(i.datetime_to_float())
      5 

AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'datetime_to_float'
```

What do I have to change here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is `time`? and as @leuchtum answered, you call your function as if it was a method of a class, which seems not applicable here.

Comment: `time`is a list with all my datetime object.

Comment: Defining a function doesn't add a method to the `datetime` class. You don't need that function at all, anyway. Change `time_in_float.append(i.datetime_to_float())` to `time_in_float.append(i.timestamp())`.

Comment: why not simply `time_in_float = [t.timestamp() for t in time]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do `time_in_float.append(datetime_to_float(i))` in your loop

Answer (score 1):

you define a function, you need to pass your `datetime.datetime` object as argument and not expect to apply the function as method

```
def datetime_to_float(d):
    return d.timestamp()


time_in_float = []

for i in time:
    time_in_float.append(datetime_to_float(i))
```

However there is no need to define a function that will only make your code more obscure, so this should be just fine:

```
time_in_float = []

for i in time:
    time_in_float.append(i.timestamp())
```

or even list comprehension

```
time_in_float = [(i.timestamp() for i in time]
```

all this assumes `i` is datetime.datetime`object and not`str`