# Convert Python datetime or date to float for representing an x-axis

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, datetime-conversion

I'm dealing with a large dataset that has dates in it (in the format "mm/dd/yyyy") and I'm trying to graph a certain metric in relation to that dates. Now since the dates need to be in the x-axis, I know I need to convert them into floats. I currently have two approaches:

1. Use string parsing to get month/year/dates, convert them to floats, and add them together like so:

```
def get_date_float(date_str):
    # date_str = something like "01/13/2021"
    m, d, y = float(date_str[:2]), float(date_str[3:5]), float(date_str[6:])
    return y + (m / 12) + (0.01 * d / num_days_in_month(int(m)))
```

*Note: `num_days_in_month` uses the `monthrange` function from the `calendar` module.*
However, this results in not-so-accurate floats for the dates. For example, the date "12/15/2020    " becomes the float "2021.004839" which is clearly wrong. I'm not sure why this is happening - I tried different operations on the m/d/y variables from above but there's always some degree of error.

2. After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337299/python-datetime-to-float-with-millisecond-precision), I tried using the `datetime`module to convert the string into a float like so:

```
def date_str_to_datetime_to_float(date_str):
    # date_str = "12/15/2020"
    datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%m/%d/%Y")
    print(datetime_obj.timestamp())
```

However, the timestamp is a very large number (# of milliseconds since some starting time?). For example, the date "12/15/2020" becomes the timestamp "1608019200.0". However, I want something like "2020.921" or something like that.

Comment: I find that datetimes usually graph fairly well on x-axis and are easier to modify in terms of duration over floats, and also more clearly demonstrate change over time. (If they have been converted from string [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html))

Comment: Ahh just graphing the datetime objects works great; thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datetime objects graph pretty well on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason the plotter does not support datetime objects for the axis, it may be necessary to provide it numbers. This function returns a list of numbers in the largest differentiating unit of the provided datetimes. It uses a dynamic range of the output. This allows the axis labels to be more human-readable than via various other transformation.

```py
from calendar import isleap, monthrange
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta as td
from typing import Optional

_ATTRIBUTES = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'microsecond']
_CONVERTERS = {
    None: lambda t: 0,
    'microsecond': lambda t: t.microsecond,
    # 'second': lambda t: t.second + t.microsecond / 1_000_000,  # Reference implementation.
    'second': lambda t: td(seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond),
    # 'minute': lambda t: t.minute + t.second / 60 + t.microsecond / 60_000_000,  # Reference implementation.
    'minute': lambda t: td(minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond) / td(minutes=1),
    # 'hour': lambda t: t.hour + t.minute / 60 + t.second / 3_600 + t.microsecond / 3_600_000_000,  # Reference implementation.
    'hour': lambda t: td(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond) / td(hours=1),
    # 'day': lambda t: t.day + t.hour / 24 + t.minute / 1_440 + t.second / 86_400 + t.microsecond / 86_400_000_000,  # Reference implementation.
    'day': lambda t: td(days=t.day, hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond) / td(days=1),
    # 'month': lambda t: t.month + t.day / (days_in_month := monthrange(t.year, t.month)[1]) + t.hour / (days_in_month * 24) + t.minute / (days_in_month * 1_440) + t.second / (days_in_month * 86_400) + t.microsecond / (days_in_month * 86_400_000_000),  # Reference implementation.
    'month': lambda t: t.month + td(days=t.day, hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond) / td(days=monthrange(t.year, t.month)[1]),  # Reference implementation.
    # 'year': lambda t: t.year + t.timetuple().tm_yday / (days_in_year := (366 if isleap(t.year) else 365)) + t.hour / (days_in_year * 24) + t.minute / (days_in_year * 1_440) + t.second / (days_in_year * 86_400) + t.microsecond / (days_in_year * 86_400_000_000),  # Reference implementation.
    'year': lambda t: t.year + td(days=t.timetuple().tm_yday, hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond) / td(days=366 if isleap(t.year) else 365),
}


def convert_datetimes_to_numbers_and_unit(datetimes: list[datetime.datetime], /) -> tuple[list[float], Optional[str]]:
    """
    Return a list of numbers representing the given datetime objects based on their largest unequal distinguishing unit of time.

    The aforementioned unit is also returned. The possible units are: year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond, None

    For example:
    - If 'hour' is the largest differentiating unit, the function will return numbers where each number
      represents the datetime in terms of hours, plus minutes (as a fraction of an hour), plus seconds (as a fraction
      of an hour), and so on.
    - If all datetimes are the same, the numbers will all be 0 and the unit will be None.

    Usage examples:
        > now = datetime.datetime.now()  # = datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 9, 18, 50, 59, 783833)
        > convert_datetimes_to_numbers_and_unit([now, now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=3), now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=3, seconds=2, microseconds=1)])
          ([50.996397216666665, 53.996397216666665, 54.029730566666665], 'minute')
        > convert_datetimes_to_numbers_and_unit([now, now + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3), now + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3, days=2, hours=1)])
          ([10.315658521443025, 10.993077876281735, 11.060902694380015], 'month')
        > convert_datetimes_to_numbers_and_unit([now, now + datetime.timedelta(weeks=52*2), now + datetime.timedelta(weeks=52*3)])
          ([2023.7747545593552, 2025.7665353812731, 2026.7637956552458], 'year')

    Limitation: DST is ignored.
    """
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77262290
    unique_tz = {t.tzinfo for t in datetimes}
    num_unique_tz = len(unique_tz)
    if num_unique_tz > 1:
        unique_tz = ', '.join(str(tz) for tz in unique_tz)
        raise TypeError(f'At most 1 unique time zone is expected, but {num_unique_tz} exist: {unique_tz}')

    largest_unit = next((attr for attr in _ATTRIBUTES if (len({getattr(t, attr) for t in datetimes}) > 1)), None)
    converter = _CONVERTERS[largest_unit]
    numbers = [converter(t) for t in datetimes]
    return numbers, largest_unit
```

---

Given the example Dec-15-2020 which is in the question, this is how it might be used:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

first_dt = datetime(year=2020, month=12, day=15)
all_dt = [first_dt, first_dt + timedelta(days=400), first_dt + timedelta(days=600)]
convert_datetimes_to_numbers_and_unit(all_dt)
([2020.9562841530055, 2022.0520547945205, 2022.6], 'year')
```

As such, the matching output for Dec-15-2020 in this example is 2020.96 which is along the lines of what was expected.